# How to show $t{B^{2}_t}+t^2$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-addapted process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

How to show $t{B^{2}_t}+t^2$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process? Here $B_t$ is Brownian Process.

Please Help

Comment: Please show what you did (and avoid all-caps).

Comment: The definition is to write as the sum of indicator function, but I cannot think of how it is expressed as indicator functions.

Comment: Do you want $B_t^2$ or $B_{t^2}$?

Comment: @martini:sorry for the mistake. I want ${B_t}^2$

Comment: The definition is certainly not "to write as (a) sum of indicator function(s)".

Answer (score 3):

As $B_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable, $B_t^2$ is also (note that continuous functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are measurable), so is $tB_t^2 + t^2$.